# Data set generator

Tags: regression, generator

I'd like to ask if someone knows a good data set generator for multi-target/Multivariate regression

All the best

Richard

Comment: A starting point would be to try the $data()$ command in R.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to generate data that's appropriate for multivariate regression is to draw random variates from a multivariate distribution, such as the multivariate normal distribution. Just write the mean vector as a function of your covariates. Sampling from a multivariate normal distribution can be done with, for example, `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` in Python or `MASS::mvrnorm` in R.